# regex - replace last occurrence of chracters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like the following.

```
 "file":"Send/P.dfsghgsdfgsdfg.002.P001.test--1jc73ixtc7fd8.xml",
 "bindataId":690059034230943545254345,
 "msgId":"565638.4997972882814290494.52343220",
 "orgnlMsgId":"-1jc73ixtc7fd8"
```

*It looks like an object but actually it is not.*

They may have `file` key. If they have, it may contains `orgnlMsgId's` value. For example in this case, file contains `-1jc73ixtc7fd8`.

I need to match `orgnlMsgId's` value irrespective of file contains its value or does not. I had used negated-lookahead (`/orgnlMsgId":"(.*)(?<!.xml)"/`) but found out that Firefox does not support it. So I can not use look-ahead or look-behind.

How can I match orgnlMsgId's value?

Comment: `I have json objects` ... then use a JSON parser (e.g. JavaScript).  _Don't_ try to bend regex to handle your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regex. Use includes

```js
var x={"file":"Send/P.dfsghgsdfgsdfg.002.P001.test--1jc73ixtc7fd8.xml",
 "bindataId":690059034230943545254345,
 "msgId":"565638.4997972882814290494.52343220",
 "orgnlMsgId":"-1jc73ixtc7fd8"
}
if(x.file.includes(x.orgnlMsgId))
console.log(true)
else
console.log(false)
```

```js
var x='"file":"Send/P.dfsghgsdfgsdfg.002.P001.test--1jc73ixtc7fd8.xml","bindataId":690059034230943545254345,"msgId":"565638.4997972882814290494.52343220","orgnlMsgId":"-1jc73ixtc7fd8"';
 x.split(x.split('"orgnlMsgId":')[1].split('"').join('')).length>2?console.log(true):console.log(false)
```

Comment: You can still parse the string using JSON.parse() to convert it to JSON object provided the strings is a representation of the object

Comment: Again updated the question. It looks like an object but is is not. It contains an HTML template also.

Comment: Check the second snip. Still no need to use regex. Use split and join